# linking upload picture codes with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, upload, image-uploading

I am making something like a profile picture. I made a form to upload pictures and upload_file codes are succeed, but I only need a way to link the upload with mysql. or any way to make the uploaded picture a profile picture.

this is the codes I had done:

selecting pictures (upload_form.php)

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and upload_file.php

```
 <?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1048576)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

those codes are succeed to upload the pictures. so my next step is how to make it profile picture??

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution and doesn't contain any code.

But it may give some idea of what you actually need to do on a high-level.

**Assumptions**

1. You are uploading as a profile picture. So, you already have users table and code to create new users.
2. Users will login to their account and Upload a picture

**Database - Users Table**

1. Have a column with the name picture in the user's table. Which can be null. We will store uploaded picture's file name in this field for each user. This is a string.

**Upload - Process**

1. You are already uploading the picture. Now give some unique name to the uploaded file name, instead of the name with which user uploaded the picture.

   - Because, user 1 and user 2 may both upload a file with the name *pic.jpg* and you end up having only one *pic.jpg* in the uploaded folder.
   - There should be some unique field per user in your users table. May be email or username. So, it is a better idea to make a md5 hash of username + time and use it as the file name.
   - Don't use the user's id as the file name. Even though it helps you to get working code quickly, some body with a simple script can get all your user's pictures.
2. Create a folder with the name "upload" or something similar in your static folder and upload the user's picture to that folder.
3. After successfully uploading the picture store the file name in the user's table under the column "pciture" that you added above.

**Showing Profile Picture**

1. Definitely you want to show the profile picture with the user's name.
2. So, while fetching the user's details, also get the picture name from database and show that with the proper path.

**What Next**

1. User's may upload a big picture as their profile picture. So, it is not a good idea to show a 5 mega pixel image for a profile picture of size : 100px X 120px. So, while uploading it is better to re-size and crop and store it so that you save on end-user's bandwidth.
2. Also make sure that you keep user's original image. May be you need user's pic in different size at a later time while adding new features to your website.
3. Make sure that when user deletes their account, delete their original pic too. :)
4. You can use gd2 or ImageMagick for this.

Hope this will give some idea of what you need to look next.

Comment: from assumption for current there is only admin-user wish is limit to 2 admins only those 2 admins had they own account and yes they have to login and upload a picture.
from Database: I have admin table contain ID, AdminName, e.mail and password column (and its used fro login too)

Comment: Upload - process: 1 and 2 yes true. I am asking this question to know what should I do exactly in 3 and next steps

Comment: currently I would like to know how to link the upload with database and the path. thank you for your help